How to calculate Tc in single cycle method?
consider a processor that goes through the following six stages while executing an instruction



Column A
Column B




If
120 ns


Id
200 ns


ex
150 ns


MR
150 ns


Mw
180 ns


WB
250 ns



Find out the total time for the given code below in a single cycle method.
addi  $s0,$zero,100
sw    $t0,20($s0)
lw    $t1,36($s0)
sub   $s2,$t0,$t1
or    $t0,$t1,$s2

I only know about there is 5 stages

if
id
ex
mem
wb

but in this question mem is divided in 2 parts Mr , Mw
in my method if we count mem as one stage 150+180= 330
Tc= 1050 ns.

If the processor is a single cycle processor, which is running all those "stages" more or less one after another for the same instruction within a single cycle, then the analysis that's needed is critical path analysis.
In critical path analysis we trace the flow of (control & data) signals from the beginning of the cycle (starting with the program counter and fetch from instruction memory), to the end of the cycle when register updates happen.
If two or more components can be run in parallel, they would be, and so the critical path for them goes to the slowest of such.  Things that run in series have to have their durations summed and things that run in parallel, we take the max of their durations.  So, very conceptually, the formula looks like sum ( ..., max ( , ), ... ) where the max's represent things that can run in parallel.
However to get more detailed, we would use a block diagram and assign times of input arrival, and given component duration, then set time of each output in the block diagram.  The analysis requires knowing what can run in parallel and what in series, which can be identified by the wiring of the block diagram in connecting the outputs of components to the inputs of successors.  This analysis allows for components that can run in parallel but also don't necessarily start (receive their inputs) at the same time due to predecessors differing.

consider a processor that goes through the following six stages while executing an instruction

So, you have to ask yourself, does the corresponding block diagram simply connect each stage to the next in the list or is there any opportunity for parallelism?  Note that MIPS has no individual instructions that both read and write memory.

If the processor is pipelined, which means all stages overlap but in each cycle are running for different instructions, so then the cycle time is simply the max of each of the individual stages, since the whole processor runs one of those slowest stages each cycle (for a different instruction).
